# Parse cloud code login signup example

Tags: parse-platform, javascript, parse-cloud-code

I have searched for a lot of tutorials to find actual cloud code functions for a user login signup with username as my email, in Parse. I only have an overall idea about how to get through Parse. But examples are scarce. Kindly share with me some examples or even good tutorials( I have already read the docs in parse.com ). I actually want to have API's set up for login and signup using Parse.

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering off my phone so I don't want to try to type out a bunch of code, however, for signups what you could do is ask the user for their username, password, email, etc....send that to Cloud Code and using the master key, create a new object just like you would for a custom class.

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```